# How can pickerview have date component to it?

Tags: iphone, date, customization, uipickerview, uidatepicker

I need to add a date component to my PickerView. Any ideas on how to get the date component? One way is to manually maintain all the date related info, take current date add and subtract to get the reqd dates, but this is very tedious, any other methods?

[image: Integrated PickerView with date component]

EDIT:I have not yet got about to writing the code, i need some ideas on how to go about getting the values for the date component(not UI). One solution I have is to take the current date and then use the 'dateByAddingTimeInterval' to maintain the the last 50 and next 50 days, but his approach is very crude. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Good question but I think the only way is to create your custom view via delegate's methods.

Comment: Custom View is fine, so you mean have 2 pickers placed next to one another? But can the required UI detail be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and used the same approach that i had mentioned in the question(given below). Even though its crude, it gets the work done. I have not tested this approach for large values of date in the third component. As of now i just have (30+30) values including the current date and its pretty stable and quick.

"One solution I have is to take the current date and then use the '**dateByAddingTimeInterval**' to maintain the the last 50 and next 50 days, but his approach is very crude."

Answer (score 1):

*Going from comments here:*

I suggest you to try this one approach.

1. Creating **one** `UIPickerView`.
2. Setting its parameters (step 1 in class that implements `UIPickerViewDataSource`):

   1. Implement `- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView` that will provide number of components. In your case it is **3** : `return 3;`
   2. Implement `- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component` that will return the number of row for each component.
3. Setting its parameters (step 1 in class that implements `UIPickerViewDelegate`):

   1. Implement `- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view` which will return `UILabel` for component **0** and **1** and `UIView` with two `UILabel`'s as subview (gray one and black one) for component **2**

Also you can make more customization by implementing other methods in delegate class:

**Setting the Dimensions of the Picker View**

```
– pickerView:rowHeightForComponent:
– pickerView:widthForComponent:
```

**Setting the Content of Component Rows**

```
– pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:
```

Complete list of methods you can find here: [UIPickerViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html)

Comment: Oops, i should have been more clearer, the UI is fine, i am worried about the values that i shall feed to the row components. Esp the third component, how do i replicate values for the whole calendar in the Pickerview.

Comment: And what is the problem in generating this values? Post your current code

Comment: UpVote for the detailed explanation but that is not what i was looking for, I have Edited the question.

Comment: I think, using `dateByAddingTimeInterval` in good approach. Cannot suggest you anything better.